# Bounds on the expectation of a product of zonal spherical harmonics

Tags: pr.probability, harmonic-analysis, spherical-geometry

Let us consider a $d-1$ dimensional sphere $S^{d-1}$, and for a point $a \in S^{d-1}$ let $Z_{a,k} : S^{d-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the [zonal spherical harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonal_spherical_harmonics) of degree $k$ in the direction $a$, with normalization $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim S^{d-1}} Z_{a,k}^2(X) = 1$ (where the expectation is chosen over $X$ uniformly distributed over a sphere). Now, let $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_s \in S^{d-1}$ for $s \ll d$ be a collection of vectors such that for $i\not=j$ we have $|\langle a_i, a_j \rangle| \leq \delta$. Let us assume moreover that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \leq \delta$.

I am wondering if
$$
        \mathbb{E}_{X \sim S^{d-1}} \prod_{i\leq s} Z_{a_i, k_i}(X) \leq (s \delta)^{\Omega(K)} \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
for $K = \sum k_i$.

Are those kind of inequalities likely to be true or have been considered before?

### A bit of context

An analogous limiting statement, where $d\to \infty$, is relatively easy to prove and variants of it seem to be well-known to experts in the literature (for example, similar calculation appears in [1], but I do not know the canonical reference for this exact statement). Here, the entire problem reduces to the [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) --- i.e. if $H_k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are Hermite polynomials of degree $k$ with (somewhat non-standard) normalization $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)} H_k(X)^2 = 1$, and again $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_s$ are on a sphere satisfying $|\langle a_i, a_j \rangle| \leq \delta$, then the following inequality holds

$$
\mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)} \prod_i H_{k_i}(\langle a_i, Z \rangle) \leq (s \delta)^{\Omega(K)}.
$$

### Motivation

Let us consider some fixed univariate function $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and again a collection of vectors $a_1, \ldots a_s \in S^{d-1}$ with bounded inner products by $\delta$. We can draw a uniformly random vector $Z$ from a sphere and look at a coupling of random variables $X_i = f(\langle a_i, Z \rangle)$. Clearly all $X_i$ have the same marginal distribution and they are not independent --- but hopefully, as long as all $a_i$ are nearly orthogonal, the dependencies between $X_i$ should be relatively mild. To quantitatively control those dependencies, we try for all subsets $T \subset \{1, \ldots k\}$ to upper bound the central mixed moment $\mathbb{E} \prod_{i \in T} (X_i - \mathbb{E} X_i)$. A natural way to try to control those moments is just to expand $f(\langle a_i, Z\rangle)$ into spherical harmonics, expand the entire product, and separately bound all terms appearing in the large sum --- those are exactly the terms as in inequality (1).

This idea is easy to implement in Gaussian space with Hermite polynomials, but I was not able to do it on a sphere, and neither was I able to find similar calculations in the literature.

[1] : *Combinatorial applications of Hermite polynomials*, R. Azor, J. Gillis and J.D. Victor